# CSS | Only apply styling to Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

**Currently I am testing the website on Internet Explorer 10 and 11.**

Currently I have a stylesheet which has some styling in it that should only apply to when the visiter is browsing the website using Internet Explorer. I tried to use conditional comments but they are not supported in Internet Explorer 10 and 11.

I was wondering if someone has dealt with this issue before and could push me into the right direction. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for IE10 and IE11. It will add class to html tag.

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<script>
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {  
    document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';  
}  
</script>
<!--<![endif]--> 

<script>
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
      doc = document.documentElement;
if((ua.match(/rv:11.0/i))){
    doc.className = doc.className + " ie11";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments are no longer supported

Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5.

```
This Applies to Internet Explorer 10 and later.
```

For more info **[Read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

you can add this tag in head like

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8)]><!-->
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and by inheriting the class u can change the design of it like

```
.ie7 body{background: transparent}
```

Comment: As I stated in the OP, conditional comments aren't supported in internet Explorer 10 and 11.

Comment: You can even use like jquery function 

if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
  $("html").addClass("ie10");
}

Answer (score 0):

Add the user agent to the html like so:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
```

the user agent for IE10 is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)
```

This will result in this:

```
<html data-useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)">
```

And then you can style:

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] h1 {
 color: blue;
}
```

So the header will only be blue in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  #myClass { color: red; }
}
```

see CSS hacks http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/